# Basic Powershell script strange behaviour

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I have small script. Which i want test it with "If, else statement".
I have the same value variables but when try to compare it, it gives else condition, but it should give true condition.
Below are my vars with results.

```
$ASE1=Get-Content -path "C:\Program Files\Kratos\Tools\ASE\cnf\_ASE.cnf" | out-string -Stream | Select-String "VERSION"
```

> Version 85

```
$ASE2=Get-Content -path "C:\ProgramData\Kratos\Tools\NaCl\Files\xASE.cnf"| out-string -Stream | Select-String "VERSION"
```

> Version 85

**if($ASE1 -eq $ASE2) {
echo "equal"}
else {
echo "not equal"}**

This above small script return me "not equal" condition but in true this vars is equal to each other. Do you know what im doing wrong ?

Comment: I''ve fix it, by changing "-ne" to "-notmatch".

Comment: Then post an actual answer

Answer (score 0):

Select-String doesn't return a string but a `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` Object

- As these `Objects` differ ***your*** result is expected. (view output of `$ASE1,$ASE2`)
- Both Get-Content and Out-String from your example are superfluous.
- As the pattern is RegEx based, you might use a (capture group) to just get the digits of your version.

```
$Pattern = 'Version (\d+)'
$ASE1 = Select-String -Pattern $Pattern -Path "C:\Program Files\Kratos\Tools\ASE\cnf\_ASE.cnf"
$ASE2 = Selcet-String -Pattern $Pattern -Path "C:\ProgramData\Kratos\Tools\NaCl\Files\xASE.cnf"
if($ASE1.Matches.Groups[1].Value -eq $ASE2.Matches.Groups[1].Value) { 
    "equal"
} else {
    "not equal"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-readcount 0 works the same as piping to out-string.
   Piping out-string or get-content to select-string puts a bottleneck on your script.

```
$ASE1 = Get-Content "C:\Program Files\Kratos\Tools\ASE\cnf\_ASE.cnf" -ReadCount 0
$ASE2 = Get-Content "C:\ProgramData\Kratos\Tools\NaCl\Files\xASE.cnf" -ReadCount 0
[regex]$Pattern = 'Version\s\d+'
if ($Pattern.Matches($ASE1).value -eq $Pattern.Matches($ASE2).value) { 
    "equal"
}
else {
    "not equal"
}
```